# How do I dump view schemas for a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database, dump, schema

I have a MySQL database for which I wish to dump schemas for views. How do I do this? I tried mysqldump with --no-data, but that only dumps table schemas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you might either be passing some other options to mysqldump, or using a version of mysqldump that doesn't understand views (perhaps it's too old).  When I run mysqldump --no-data, it does dump out the view definitions.  See the below:

```
/*!50001 CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED */
/*!50013 DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER */
/*!50001 VIEW `t` AS select 1 AS `1` */;
```

Comment: maybe the questioner didn't have a look in the mysqldump? To dump the views commented out is a very bad style by MySQL. There should at least a hint in the docs, but there is none.

Comment: Nevermind, I was wrong. It did dump the views. Thank god. Cool.

Comment: These are conditional comments that execute depending on your version of MySQL, see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comments.html

Answer (score 5):

Use **--opt** option while making the **dump**:

```
mysqldump -hserver -uUser -ppasswd -no-data --opt export > export.sql
```

Comment: Although for security reasons, I'd not put the password on the command line, I'd let the program prompt for it.

Comment: I think we need to clarify that `export` in the command is a specific schema/database name i.e. NOT a mysqldump syntax

Answer (score 3):

Mysqldump won't have any options to dump only on views.The below command will help you to take the backup of only views.

mysql -uroot -pPassword INFORMATION_SCHEMA --skip-column-names -e "select table_name from tables where table_type = 'VIEW' and table_schema = 'sakila'" | xargs mysqldump -u root -pPassword sakila > only_views.sql

Answer (score 0):

The other answers did not but this worked for me...

```
mysqldump --skip-comments --skip-opt --complete-insert --add-drop-table --database dbname -p
```